# Describe group $(\mathbb{Z_5^*}, *_5)$ using Caylay table.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am not quite sure what $\mathbb{Z}$ means, i mean, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a set of whole numbers, but that index 5 confuses me, d don't know what it means, and again, what $*_5$ means, i mean it is a multiplication sign, but i don't know what 5 index means.

Comment: My guess would be multiplication modulo 5?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}_5 ^*$ is the set of elements in $$\mathbb{Z}_5 = \{\bar{0},\bar{1},\bar{2},\bar{3},\bar{4}\}$$

with in verses in $\mathbb{Z}_5$. Note that $\bar{a} = \{x\in \mathbb{Z} | x\equiv a \pmod{5}\}$

You can check that $$\mathbb{Z}_5 ^* = \mathbb{Z}_5-\{0\}$$ And I assume $*_5$ is multiplication modulo $5$, i.e. $4*_54 = 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5.$